# Track clicks on third-party sites from Chrome extension

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have Chrome extension. When the user visit some site (e.g. Amazon.com) he can drag or load img of product to his account and leave review for other users.
  I want to know is it possible from extension to know if user click button 'Buy' or 'Add to cart' on Amazon.

Comment: technically, with enough permissions, you can get all DOM information using extensions. So, it is possible